# .htaccess Rewrite to Force Trailing Slash

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect non trailing slash to trailing slash at the end , my wordpress is in sub dictionary http://domain.com/blog/

I have two `.htaccess` files, one in the root and one in the wordpress folder.

I put that code in the root .htaccess with no luck

```
RewriteEngine On     
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/blog/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Wordpress give 200 OK with the two versions with and without trailing slash and that hurts my SEO

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: Please check the updated post

Answer (score 0):

You are close but need to remove one `RewriteCond` and modify the `RewriteRule` slightly:

```
RewriteEngine On     
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

You could also consider adding something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`.  Otherwise you may be preventing the default directory index behavior.

Good luck.

Comment: I edited this to remove the `/blog` from the rewrite rule.  It will be prepended to the rewrite destination due to th `RewriteBase` statement